# Cannot filter out rows with empty column value from a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this :

```
Note.Reco     Raison.Reco     DATE_SAISIE     idpart
    9                          19/03/2014     102856992
    1       always good        19/03/2014     102853645
    8       very good service  19/03/2014     1072309
    10                         19/03/2014     191391
```

I try to filter out rows for which `raison.Reco` column value is empty. It means I expect this result:

```
Note.Reco     Raison.Reco     DATE_SAISIE     idpart
    1       always good        19/03/2014     102853645
    8       very good service  19/03/2014     1072309
```

I try with this R code :

```
trainfilter <- filter(train, !is.na(Raison.Reco) | Raison.Reco != "")
```

But when I do :
trainfilter to see the result, I get the same inital not filtered dataframe.

Any idea please?

Comment: Please check if you have `""` or `" "`.  Perhaps `filter(train, trimws(Raison.Reco) !="")`

Comment: @akrun, yes it works now! Tahnk you very much, you save my life :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a case of white spaces instead of blank.  One option is to trim the white spaces to `""` using `trimws` and then subset

```
library(dplyr)
filter(train, trimws(Raison.Reco) !="")
```

Or with `grepl` to check if there are zero or more white space from start (`^`) to end (`$`) of string

```
filter(train, !grepl("^\\s*$", Raison.Reco))
```

Or the same with `subset`

```
subset(train, trimws(Raison.Reco) !="")
```